# How to load Hy package in zipapp?

Tags: python, hy, zipapp

I have a Python script (as entry point), a [Hy](https://github.com/hylang/hy) library (simply add two columns) and an input data file:

```
$ cat add_cols/app.py 
import hy
import sys
from mylib import add2col

def main():
    inp = sys.argv[1]
    out = sys.argv[2]
    print(f'read file {inp}, and convert to file {out}')
    add2col(inp, out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

$ cat add_cols/mylib.hy 
(import [pandas :as pd])

(defn add2col [inpfile outfile]
  (setv inp (.read_csv pd inpfile))
  (assoc inp "cola"  (+ (get inp "cola") (get inp "colb")))
  (.to_csv inp outfile :index False))

$ cat demo.csv
cola,colb
1,2
1,2
1,2
1,2
1,2
1,2
1,2
1,2
1,2
1,2
```

I can run it directly and get the result:

```
$ cd add_cols
$ python app.py ../demo.csv res.csv
read file ../demo.csv, and convert to file res.csv
$ cat res.csv
cola,colb
3,2
3,2
3,2
...
```

Now I try to run it as [zipapp](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipapp.html):

```
$ python -m zipapp add_cols -m 'app:main'
$ python add_cols.pyz demo.csv res.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leo/apps/miniconda3/envs/hylang/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/leo/apps/miniconda3/envs/hylang/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "add_cols_hy.pyz/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "add_cols_hy.pyz/app.py", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylib'
```

Why `mylib` can't be loaded?
How to load Hy library in zipapp?

Environment:

- Python 3.6 in Anaconda
- Ubuntu 16.04

Thanks!

Comment: Try checking if this works with the latest Hy. If not, it's probably a Hy bug, so post to Hy's issue list.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is a bug. It's now [Hy's issue #1774](https://github.com/hylang/hy/issues/1774).